# Eclipse PyDev PyQt5 - where does stderr go?

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt5, pydev, stderr

I've installed PyDev on Eclipse 2020-09, and I'm now experimenting with PyQt5.

When I've put in some code which is bad in some way, so bad that the PyQt5 code exits, and the main GUI window disappears, I can't see any error message or traceback in the console.

The console only outputs `print` statements (`stdout`).

I can see that the button "Show console when standard error changes" (at the bottom, in the console dialog) is depressed, if this is relevant.

If I run the file at the W10 CLI I get a proper traceback print out.

Comment: I believe that if you do: `sys.stderr.write("Something\n")` it should appear in the console... your problem is probably that qt itself is exiting without printing anything.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny possibly... If I run the file at the W10 CLI I get a proper traceback print out... so it appears that the fault may lie with the combination (PyDev + PyQt5) ... i.e. Eclipse is "swallowing" or "hiding" the `stderr` output. Frustrating.